# Non-member conversion, different types same members

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two classes I cannot modify, both have exactly the same members:

```
class Pose1 {
    public:
    double x,y;
};
class Pose2 {
   public:
   double x,y;
};
```

One part of the code uses Pose1 the other one uses Pose2. Is there a way to implicit convert these into each other? Now I have to write all the time

```
Pose1 p1(0.5, 0.5);
Pose2 p2(p1.x,p2.y);
```

I know I can write a conversion function which just does that once. But I have a lot of different types with lots of arguments.

Is there any way I can do something like:

```
Pose2 p2  = static_cast<Pose2>(p1);
```

I cannot use member function because I cannot change this code.

Thank you!

Comment: I suppose `Pose2 p2 = *reinterpret_cast<Pose2 *>(&p1);` should at least normally work.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm curious about whether it would work, doesn't it violates the [type aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) rules?

Comment: introducing this reinterpret cast means that the author of the Pose1 and Pose2 classes may never safely maintain his code again, in case he introduces a subtle bug into the consumer's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. `Pose1` and `Pose2` are different types with no common bases. The fact that they happen to have the same member types and names doesn't matter. If you want to make them convertible into each other, you have to explicitly provide that support.

One way is to provide an external conversion function:

```
template <typename Pose, typename T>
Pose toPose(const T& pose) {
    return Pose{pose.x, pose.y};
}

Pose2 pose2 = toPose<Pose2>(pose1);
```

Alternatively, you can write a type_trait using `void_t` to see if something is a `Pose` or not:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_pose : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct is_pose<T, void_t<
               std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(T::x), double>::value>,
               std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(T::y), double>::value>>>
: std::true_type { };
```

And then just write "pose-like" constructors for all of your poses:

```
class Pose2 {
    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_pose<T>::value>>
    Pose2(T&& pose_like)
    : x(pose_like.x)
    , y(pose_like.y)
    { }
};

Pose2 pose{pose1}; // works
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
template <class Dest, class Src>
Dest pose_cast(const Src &src)
{
    return Dest(src.x, src.y) ;
}
```

usage:

```
Pose1 p1 ;
Pose2 p2 = pose_cast<Pose2, Pose1>(p1)
```

Works for both conversions.

Comment: You may omit `Src` in the call: `pose_cast<Pose2>(p1);`

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
class Pose1 {
    public:
    double x,y;
};
/*class Pose2 {
   public:
   double x,y;
};*/

typedef Pose1 Pose2;
```

I don't understand why not?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

but you can save yourself a lot of work by writing this function overload set and putting them in a utility header file:

```
inline Pose2 to_pose2(const Pose1& p1) {
    return Pose2 { p1.x, p1.y };
}

inline Pose2& to_pose2(Pose2& p2) {
    return p2;
}

inline const Pose2& to_pose2(const Pose2& p2) {
    return p2;
}
```

which can then be used like so:

```
void function_that_needs_a_pose2(const Pose2& p2);

Pose1 p1;
Pose2 p2;

function_that_needs_a_pose2(to_pose2(p1));
function_that_needs_a_pose2(to_pose2(p2));
```

...or you can hold your Pose[n] objects in a PoseHolder, which does allow implicit casts:

```
inline Pose2 to_pose2(const Pose1& p1) {
    return Pose2 { p1.x, p1.y };
}

inline Pose1 to_pose1(const Pose2& p1) {
    return Pose1 { p1.x, p1.y };
}

struct PoseHolder {
    PoseHolder(Pose1 p1) : _pose1 { std::move(p1) } {}
    PoseHolder(Pose2 p2) : _pose2 { std::move(p2) } {}


    operator const Pose1&() const {
        if (!_pose1.is_initialized()) {
            _pose1 = to_pose1(_pose2.value());
        }
        return _pose1.value();
    }

    operator const Pose2&() const {
        if (!_pose2.is_initialized()) {
            _pose2 = to_pose2(_pose1.value());
        }
        return _pose2.value();
    }

private:
    mutable boost::optional<Pose1> _pose1;
    mutable boost::optional<Pose2> _pose2;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get an implicit conversion if you can't modify at least one of the two types.

Some might suggest casting one to the other via reference, but that's still not implicit, so you might as well write a conversion function and not have undefined behavior. (The cast violates the strict aliasing rules, and thus is UB.)

Answer (score 0):

The memory layout of the class as you have listed it, should be the same.

There is no implicit conversion, but you can just cast the pointer types.

If one of your classes starts having a virtual table however all bets are off as it is compiler dependent and you need a real explicit conversion.

You might want to wrap the conversions in a function so it's neat and if you need to do more work later, you have it encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

another solution if you don't want to specify the destination type in the cast:

```
#include <iostream>

class Pose1 {
public:
    double x,y;
};
class Pose2 {
public:
    double x,y;
};

namespace detail {
    template<class T, class U>
    struct PoseCaster {

        operator U
        () const
        {
            return U { _source.x, _source.y };
        }

        operator
        const T&
        () const
        {
            return _source;
        }

        const T& _source;
    };
}

detail::PoseCaster<Pose1, Pose2> pose_cast(const Pose1& pose) {
    return detail::PoseCaster<Pose1, Pose2> { pose };
}

detail::PoseCaster<Pose2, Pose1> pose_cast(const Pose2& pose) {
    return detail::PoseCaster<Pose2, Pose1> { pose };
}

void funca(const Pose1&) {
    std::cout << "funca" << std::endl;
}
void funcb(const Pose2&) {
    std::cout << "funcb" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Pose1 a;
    Pose2 b;

    funca(pose_cast(a));
    funca(pose_cast(b));
    funcb(pose_cast(a));
    funcb(pose_cast(b));
}
```